# Basic python, how to return lists of lists when reading a text file

Tags: python, list, loops

im trying to store each new line of a text file as a different list within a list, where the characters of that nested list are also individual cells. Right now it only appends the ending character of each line, not sure why due to the nested while loop. Anyone see the mistakes? Thanks

```
def read_lines(filename):

    ls_1 = []
    x = open(filename, 'r') 
    i = 0 
    t = 0
    while True: #nested while loop to read lines and seperate lines into individual characters (cells)
        read = x.readline()
        if read == '':
            break
        st = read.strip("''\n''")
        while t < len(st):
            ls_2 = []
            ls_2.append(st[t])
            t += 1
        ls_1.append(ls_2) #append a new list to the original list every time the while loop resets and a new line is read
        #ls_2.clear() # removes contents so the next loop doesn't repeat the first readline (doesnt work for unkown reason)
        t = 0 # resets the index of read so the next new line can be read from start of line
        i += 1
    x.close()
    return ls_1
```

Whole txt file:

Baby on board, how I've adored
That sign on my car's windowpane.
Bounce in my step,
Loaded with pep,
'Cause I'm driving in the carpool lane.
Call me a square,
Friend, I don't care.
That little yellow sign can't be ignored.
I'm telling you it's mighty nice.
Each trip's a trip to paradise
With my baby on board!

Comment: post the first 10 lines of your file

Comment: It really looks like you are doing this the hard way. Your problem probably stems from creating a new `ls_2 = []` in each iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: @PascalVilhime don't post the text as a comment. Edit the question and put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The *reason* you are only getting the last character is because you create *a new list inside your inner loop:

```
    while t < len(st):
        ls_2 = []
        ls_2.append(st[t])
        t += 1
    ls_1.append(ls_2)
```

Instead, you would have to do:

```
    ls_2 = []
    while t < len(st):

        ls_2.append(st[t])
        t += 1
    ls_1.append(ls_2)
```

However, don't use while loops to read from files, file objects are iterators, so just use a for-loop. Similarly, don't use a while loop to iterate over a string.

Here is how you would do it, Pythonically:

```
result = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        result.append(list(line.strip()))
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    result = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

You almost *never* use while-loops in Python. Everything is iterator based.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason i'm using while loops is because my course hasn't taught for-loops, being a more 'general' intro  programming course opposed to a python course (first sem).

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you to use the function **readlines** from python, that way you can iterate of each line of the opened file, then you can cast the string to list, by doing that you generate a list with all characters that compose that string (which seems to be what you want).

Try using the following code:

```
def read_lines(filename):
    x = open(filename, 'r') 
    ls_1 = [list(line.strip()) for line in x.readlines()]
    x.close()
    return ls_1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes this definitely looks like a much more efficient method, however just so it doesn't look sus i'll still use the while loop method as i've been taught.